# Link in php echo

Tags: php

How can I have a php echo that work as link.
I saw other answer on that theme but I can't achieve a working solution.

My script is:

```
 <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'website',true)):?>
     <div class="info-inner">
         <label><?php _e('Web:','colabsthemes');?></label>
         <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'website',true);?></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: You put an `<a href="foo">` in it.

Comment: To begin with, do you know how to make a link in static HTML?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. To what URL do you want your hyperlink to point?

Comment: The actual script give just a not linkable "web adress": what i would to achive is that the "web adress" be linkable... You can see example in demo.colorlabsproject.com/salvatore/listing/mardan-palace-hotel (contact informations)
I need to link to the same "web adress"... Is an adress inserted by users when they create new listings...thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo '<a href="site_url">Link content</a>';
?>
```

You add the rest.

Specify what do you want to achieve - link to a post with a specific id or what?

Comment: The actual script give just a not linkable web adress: what i would to achive is that the web adress be linkable...
You can see example in http://demo.colorlabsproject.com/salvatore/listing/mardan-palace-hotel/ (contact informations)

thanks

Comment: You need to specify the url you want the link to go when clicked.

Comment: The same web adress...
Is an adress inserted by users when they create new listings...

Comment: The problem with answers to unclean questions is that they don't make much sense even though they answer the question. Of course, instead of opening PHP mode to emit static HTML with an `echo` you could just type the static HTML as is.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm sorry for my bad english, but I think that is a simple problem that I' can't explaine correctly.
If you to the sample web: http://demo.colorlabsproject.com/salvatore/listing/mardan-palace-hotel/ you can see a "Contact" section and a a web adress that user insert when create new hotel record.
Now with the actual script I can see the web name text, user inserted, but a simple text that does't work as a link, and what I need is a linkable     web adress... 
Anyway thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your intent to help me.
In the end I paid a professional who helped me with a very simple solution, which is:

```
<label><?php _e('Web:','colabsthemes');?></label>
<span><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'website',true);?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'website',true);?></a></span>
```